# UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't tap while UIScrollView is scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Basically I have a **scrollView**, on which there is **another view**.
On that view I also have a **UITapGestureRecognizer**.

I'm animating scrolling of the scrollView. However, during this scrolling animation, tap gesture recognizer doesn't actually recognize taps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the code of your animation.

Answer (score 0):

Without code We can't give suggestion but try with below code might be useful for you!

```
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tapGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Answer (score 0):

For best practise, you can use button action instead of `UITapGesture` by adding `UIButton`. the reason is simple, to manage the button is far much simple then the `UITapGesture` but I am not saying use `UIButton` instead of tap gesture all the time, its all about your requirement.

For your case, add this line

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

and make sure your view is added in the `UITapGesture`and `UITapGesture` method is properly implemented in your code work.

For more basic, go with these two tutorials,

[First tutorial](https://thatthinginswift.com/gesture-recognizers-swift/)  |
[Second tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial)

If you still face any problem then let me know.